# Start an event at specific time

Tags: c++, .net, timer

I'm trying to set an event at specific time. But the timer always was late for at least 20 seconds, sometimes one minute. I can't figure out what's going on. The code is here

```
DateTime nextScheduleTime = DateTime::Today.Add(_configManager->FMSInterface->RetrieveRefDateTime); //// the retrieve ref datetime is 4am every day

while (DateTime::Now > nextScheduleTime)
{
 nextScheduleTime = nextScheduleTime.AddDays(1.0);
 }

nextScheduleInterval = nextScheduleTime.SubtractDateTime::Now).TotalMilliseconds;
_tdsStationTimer->Interval = nextScheduleInterval;
_tdsStationTimer->Enabled = true;
```

I cant tell what's wrong with the code.

Comment: if its a built-in timer I believe those have a max interval of Int16.MaxValue

Comment: it is System::Timers::Timer, the max interval is Int32.MaxValue. I traced the interval value. I calculated with Calculator, it should be fired on the right time.

Comment: Maybe nothing is wrong with the code.  You can set a timer, but the operating system does not guarantee any particular responsiveness.  This clearly depends upon the operating system, and what other things are running.  On Windows, if the program is sitting there for a long time not running (just waiting for an event) the virtual memory can be swapped out to disk.  Then, when the event fires, it can take a few seconds, even longer, to swap everything back into memory.  I don't know your specific environment, but are you running into simply a delay in the time to wake up the program?

Comment: Suggestion: schedule two timers.  One about 2 minutes ahead of the other.  Ignore the time of the first timer, but just use that to assure that the system is swapped into memory.  Then see if the second timer fires (and is handled) on time.